# How to get data (not value or name) from radio options to POST to database

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a set of options that are generated based on `database` count. For example, if a group has 4 members, 4 radio option pairs of yes and no will show:

```
Name 1

 - Attending? Yes / No

Name 2

 - Attending? Yes / No

etc
```

I'm trying to then get all the names of the guests who have clicked "yes", they are attending.

I can't do `$_POST['radio_name']` as all radio pairings have different `name`'s and the `value` of all of them are set to "yes".

For example, here are the fields for 2 guests:

```
<?php foreach ($results as $result){ 

  $party = $result['party']; // "John, Doe" in DB varchar 
  $party_guests = explode(",", $party);

  foreach ($party_guests as $index=>$guest){ ?>

  <span class="guest__name"><?php echo $guest; ?></span>
  <div class="guest__options-option">
    <span>Attending?</span>
    <div class="guest__options-group">
      <input class="guest__attendance-input" id="attending-yes-<?php echo $index; ?>" type="radio" name="attending-<?php echo $index; ?>" value="yes" required/>
      <label for="attending-yes-<?php echo $index; ?>">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="guest__options-group">
      <input class="guest__attendance-input" id="attending-no-<?php echo $index; ?>" type="radio"  name="attending-<?php echo $index; ?>" value="no" required/>
      <label for="attending-no-<?php echo $index; ?>">No</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php }
  
} ?>
```

As mentioned, I'm trying to collate a list of all those who had said yes, and no, into individual variables so I can then push them into the database (which is a varchar, the names will be separated by commas).

However, I'm unsure how to approach this as `$_POST['']` will not work dynamically (i.e. `$_POST['attending-yes-4']` will not work if there's only 2 guests generated).

Comment: Why not using an array for the radio name, it would be easier (name="attending[<?php echi $index; ?>]") ?

Comment: @Dexter0015 - But would that not leave me in the same situation? I.e. let's say the `name`s for the 2 people are `name="attending[0]"` and `name="attending[1]"` - How can I obtain the persons name from these name changes? As mentioned, sometimes there may be 5 people invited, so the array may be `attending[5]`

Comment: Wouldn't it be more suitable to "simply" use a checkbox listing the names of the attendees then? (name="attendees[]" value="<?php echo $member_name; ?>") which can contains as much values as needed (each value is the name of a member). You can then store the value as a serialized array or any other string format that suits your needs.